# How can I receive all options item inside a select tag in MVC Razor project?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

A select value can easily be obtained by this in Controller:

```
var value = Request.Form("select");
```

My select:

```
<select id="XCXCXC" multiple name="select" asp-for="NguoiNhan" class="col-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                <option value="HHH">Hello DIV!</option>
                <option value="XXX">Goodbye DIV!</option>
</select>
```

But it only works and receives the selected option. What if I want to receive a list that contains all options inside that item? How can I achieve that?

Edit resolution based on **Yiyi You**

Model:
public int Id { get; set; }

```
    public string TieuDe { get; set; }

    public DateTime? NgayKetThucCongViec { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Gio { get; set; }

    public string? NguoiThucHien { get; set; }

    public string TrangThai { get; set; }

    public string ThuocPhongban { get; set; }

    public List<string> NguoiNhan { get; set; }

    public string NoiDung { get; set; }
```

CSHTML:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="TestPostAllOption">
    <label asp-for="NguoiNhan" class="col-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"></label>
    <select id="XCXCXC" asp-for="NguoiNhan" multiple class="col-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
        <option value="HHH">Hello DIV!</option>
        <option value="XXX">Goodbye DIV!</option>
    </select>
    @*<div id="options"></div>*@
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
    [Route("test-thong-bao-select")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult TestPostAllOption(CacPhongBanVaThongTinUpsertModel selectNguoi)
    {
        var a = selectNguoi.NguoiNhan;
        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hidden inputs to put options' value.
View(use foreach to get get values of options,and add them to hidden inputs):

```
<form method="post" action="PostList">
<select name="select">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>

</select>
<div id="options"></div>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

js:

```
 $(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $("select option").each(function () {
        var s = document.createElement("input");
        s.name = "options[" + i + "]";
        s.setAttribute("value", $(this).val());
        s.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
        $("#options").append(s);
        i++;
    })
})
```

You'd better to  create a model to bind with the data which form posts.
Model:

```
public class BindModel
{
    public string select { get; set; }
    public List<string> options { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult PostList(BindModel b) {
        return Ok();
    }
```

result:
[image]

**Update:**

View:

```
<form method="post" action="PostList">
<select asp-for="NguoiNhan">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>

</select>
<div id="options"></div>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Model:

```
public class CacPhongBanVaThongTinUpsertModel
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string TieuDe { get; set; }

        public DateTime? NgayKetThucCongViec { get; set; }

        public TimeSpan Gio { get; set; }

        public string? NguoiThucHien { get; set; }

        public string TrangThai { get; set; }

        public string ThuocPhongban { get; set; }
        public string NguoiNhan { get; set; }
        public List<string> options { get; set; }

        public string NoiDung { get; set; }

    }
```

**Update2:**

If you want to use multiple select,you only need to do like this:
View（You don't need to use js）：

```
<form method="post" action="PostList">
    <select asp-for="NguoiNhan" multiple>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
        <option value="3">three</option>
    
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Model:

```
public class CacPhongBanVaThongTinUpsertModel
        {
    
            public int Id { get; set; }
    
            public string TieuDe { get; set; }
    
            public DateTime? NgayKetThucCongViec { get; set; }
    
            public TimeSpan Gio { get; set; }
    
            public string? NguoiThucHien { get; set; }
    
            public string TrangThai { get; set; }
    
            public string ThuocPhongban { get; set; }
            public List<string> NguoiNhan { get; set; }
    
            public string NoiDung { get; set; }
    
        }
```

You can get selected values from `List<string> NguoiNhan`.

Comment: But it only work in front-end side. What I want to do is passing them to my controller.

Comment: I have updated my answer,you can add hidden inputs with options' values.And when form   post,it will also post the values of hidden inputs.

Comment: It would be nice if your gif somehow also shown the debug where you passing data to Controller. I only see your data transfering inside front-end side. I want to pass it to backend, not storing all option value inside another div.

Comment: Yes,each input's data of form  will be passed to backend when form posts.And I think use a model to bind data is better.You can refer to my updated answer.

Comment: How do you bind it? I put asp-for attribute in the select but Controller receive nothing. Also for some reason the div bound with my others attribute data type but when passing to Controller, it become null as well.

Comment: It will bind with name attribute.

Comment: You mean change the name of model attributes to be like the name of select? It didn't work for me.

Comment: I have updated model CacPhongBanVaThongTinUpsertModel and view in my answer.

Comment: Big thanks to you. The only problem now is that your JS get all option of all select. I try giving a specifc select an id and pass it in JS like this $("#ChosenSelected select option") but it doesn't work. The div is now empty. How can this be solved?

Comment: `I try giving a specifc select an id and pass it in JS like this $("#ChosenSelected select option") but it doesn't work.`So you want to get selected value and text of select?

Comment: I want to get all values of a specific selection. Not all values of every select on my page.

Comment: But your type of select is not multiple,how do you have many values of a specific selection?

Comment: Oh about that. Let me edit my question. My selection does stay in multiple. Maybe that's the reason why that's the only select won't transfer option into the div. I thought they are the same. Also, what do you mean a specific selection can't have multiple values? Like one is selected and others are hidden. Even if I use a pure selection, I would still want to get value inside it but not others select.

Comment: I wish it were that simple. I will update my question with my code so you can have a better view.

Comment: So with the new code,can you work?I test in my project,and it can work.

Comment: The problem is my Model data for NguoiNhan always null. It can't receive anything. Oh wait, your answer was about receiving selected value. No, I want to receive all value inside whether them selected or not.

Comment: Have you selected values in select?And check your request form data in browser.

Comment: I just edit my reply above. But in case you don't get the notice for it, here's my reminding. Also, I want to achieve what you achieve with non-multiple select with the js thing. I want all values inside that select whether they are being selected or not, and that specific select only. Not every selection exist in my page.